# Can I open Peazip files on windows operating system?

Tags: file-format

Can I open peazip files with winrar or winzip on Windows operating system? If they can not be open is there a way to create rar and zip files that can be open on Linux and Windows operating systems?

Comment: PeaZip is available both for Linux and Windows. If you compress using the .PEA file format, then you need PeaZip. If you compress using a more common format such as .ZIP then you can open it with most compression/archiving tools. .ZIP is common on Windows, gzip (.tar.gz) is popular in Linux. 7z and XZ are great formats.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can open .zip, .rar, .tar, etc. files in Ubuntu just fine. And create said files that will open in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

[Peazip](http://www.peazip.org/index.html) is both available for Windows and Linux so any files that you create with Peazip in Ubuntu can be used in Windows.

As an alternative you can also create files in .zip and .rar formats with many popular compression tools in Ubuntu that can be opened in similar tools for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can integrate Peazip files with Windows by doing the following:

1. To send input objects to a indicated function, just right-click on any group of objects then use the Peazip entries in "SendTo" menu.
2. Drag the object or group of objects on Peazip icon. It will automatically choose the objects you provided.
3. Drag objects on your open Peazip so you can have full access to the process.
4. Double-click on your Pezip file types to open it.

You can re-arrange the application's system integration in the configuration tools in Options> System integration that requires administrative rights if really needed. Or by simply selecting Custom installation/configuration in the installer to open more options.

For more information, you can visit [Peazip's site](http://www.peazip.org)